# restriction of a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

> If $\beta$ is a  symmetric  bilinear form, non-degenerate,  on a
>   $K$-vector space $V$, then on any subspace  $W$ of $V$, $\beta : W \times 
>  W \rightarrow K $ is also a  symmetric  bilinear form non-degenerate .

Do you have any clue if this statement is right? 
I found a counter-example if 
$\beta : W \times  W' \rightarrow K $, but is it true if you take twice the same subspace?

Comment: No, it is wrong. The form $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \left(x,y\right)\mapsto xy$ is nondegenerate and symmetric, but on the subspace spanned by $\left(0,1\right)$ it becomes degenerate.

Comment: are you sure it is non degenerate on R cross R?

Comment: Oops, I said one thing and meant another. So here is what I meant: The form $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \left(\left(x_1, y_1\right), \left(x_2, y_2\right)\right) \mapsto x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1$ is nondegenerate and symmetric, but on the subspace spanned by $\left(0,1\right)$ it becomes degenerate.

Comment: The Gram matrix is non-singular: $$\det\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq 0.$$

Comment: @Marine, darij probably was thinking of the associated quadratic form (which corresponds to the bilinear form he gave later by polarization). Everything he said is good :-)